# I changed the VID on FTDI-232RQ chip and I can't change the drivers to recognize it

Tags: windows, serial-port, usb, udev, ftdi

I have an `FTDI 232RQ` chip that I used the `FT_PROG` application to change the VID on in order to use custom udev rules with it. However now that I have done that Windows will not enumerate it on a COM port. I can see the device and I can see that it has the correct settings. The chip is also no longer seen in my Linux environment.

I have used the `FT_INF` program to create custom `ftdibus` and `ftdiport` inf files using a clean download of the driver files from the `ftdichip.com` website. Attempting to install these new drivers that have the correct VID on them do not work and the chip reports `ftdi chip cannot start code 10`

I know now that I should have just changed one of the descriptor strings and keyed off the attributes string instead of the VID. But I can  not get the chip to enumerate on a COM port so that I can reprogram the VID to be default.

Is there any way to fix this or is the chip just busted?